# Luma Key (create alpha mask from image) for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, gpuimage

I'm building an app that allows people to upload an image of themselves against a white background and the app will create a silhouette of the person.

I'm having a hard time keying out the background. I am using the `GPUImage` framework and the `GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter` works great for colors, but if you get to white/black it is really hard to key out one of those colors. If I set the key to white or black it keys both the same.

Any advice?

Comment: Where's @[Brad Larson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) when you need him!

Comment: Try creating a custom filter based on the GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter, only replacing the alpha channel (`textureColor.a`) in the last mix operation with the red channel (`textureColor.r`). If you've converted your image to luminance before feeding into this, I believe that should selectively blend based on the luminance of the first image. You might need to tweak the mix order to achieve the effect you want, too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! Unfortunately, the app is crashing now. To be clear, is this the line your are referring to:

gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(textureColor.rgb, textureColor2.rgb, textureColor2.a * mixturePercent), textureColor.a);

How do I only pass in red? Everything I tried ended up with a crash:

Assertion failure in -[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter initWithVertexShaderFromString:fragmentShaderFromString:]

Comment: Change the `.a` to `.r` at the very end of that line, but leave the rest of the fragment shader as-is. You could also swap `textureColor.rgb` and `textureColor2.rgb` to change the direction in which it is keyed (off of darker or lighter luminance).

Comment: You should also know that luma keys are very hard to pull well. Most users will not have the proper lighting and exposure to make this work very well. Anyone with light skin and a bright light is bound to have spots on them that saturate the image sensor on the camera and look to a keyer like white. Even in FCP where they have a good luma keyer, if you don't film it right, it ends up looking terrible.

Comment: Assuming you found a solution, please either select the answer or self answer to close this out. Your question got up voted because people want to know!

Comment: I have a same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989942/gpuimagemovie-not-support-alpha-channel/35004399#35004399

Answer (score 1):

There is a reason why typically blue or green screens are used in movie production for chroma keying, instead of white. Anything can be white or sufficiently close to white in a photo, especially eyes or highlights or just parts of the skin. Also, it is quite hard to find an uniform white wall without shadows, cast by your subject at least.
I would recommend building a histogram, finding the most frequently used color among the brightest ones, then search for the biggest area of that color using some threshold. Then do a flood fill from that area until sufficiently different colors are encountered. All of that can be quite easily done in software, unless you want a realtime video stream.

Answer (score 0):

So, to change a white to transparent we can use this method:

```
-(UIImage *)changeWhiteColorTransparent: (UIImage *)image {
    CGImageRef rawImageRef=image.CGImage;

    const float colorMasking[6] = {222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255};

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    CGImageRef maskedImageRef=CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(rawImageRef, colorMasking);
    {
        //if in iphone
        CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, image.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, -1.0); 
    }

    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height), maskedImageRef);
    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    CGImageRelease(maskedImageRef);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
    return result;
}
```

and to replace the non transparent pixels with black, we can use:

```
- (UIImage *) changeColor: (UIImage *)image {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

    CGRect contextRect;
    contextRect.origin.x = 0.0f;
    contextRect.origin.y = 0.0f;
    contextRect.size = [image size];
    // Retrieve source image and begin image context
    CGSize itemImageSize = [image size];
    CGPoint itemImagePosition;
    itemImagePosition.x = ceilf((contextRect.size.width - itemImageSize.width) / 2);
    itemImagePosition.y = ceilf((contextRect.size.height - itemImageSize.height) );

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contextRect.size);

    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // Setup shadow
    // Setup transparency layer and clip to mask
    CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(c, NULL);
    CGContextScaleCTM(c, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextClipToMask(c, CGRectMake(itemImagePosition.x, -itemImagePosition.y, itemImageSize.width, -itemImageSize.height), [image CGImage]);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);


    contextRect.size.height = -contextRect.size.height;
    contextRect.size.height -= 15;
    // Fill and end the transparency layer
    CGContextFillRect(c, contextRect);
    CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(c);

    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

so in practice this would be:

```
-(UIImage *)silhouetteForImage:(UIImage *)img {
    return [self changeColour:[self changeWhiteColorTransparent:img]];
}
```

Obviously you would call this in a background thread, to keep everything running smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Having a play with Quartz composer and the CoreImage filters may help you. I believe that this  code should make you a silhouette:

```
- (CGImageRef)silhouetteOfImage:(UIImage *)input
{
  CIContext *ciContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
  CIImage *ciInput = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[input CGImage]];
  CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIFalseColor"];
  [filter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] forKey:@"inputColor0"];
  [filter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0] forKey@"inputColor1"];
  [filter setValue:ciInput forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
  CIImage *outImage = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
  CGImageRef result = [ciContext createCGImage:outImage fromRect:[ciInput extent]];
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a clarification of what you are trying to achieve and then understanding the differences could help. You are talking about from what I gather translucency versus transparency.

Translucency takes alpha into consideration allowing the background to be blended with the foreground based upon the alpha value for the image pixels and the kind of evaluation performed on the background buffer.

Transparency allows an image to be "masked" out in the portions with a hard alpha and threshold, and allows the background to be seen through the mask without blending. The threshold value allows limited blending based on alpha value up until the threshold.

Chromokeying is like transparency as it allows you to set a hard coded colour as the mask colour (or alpha threshold for blended keying), which allows background to be seen through portions of the foreground that possess that colour.

If your image format supports the datatype or pixelformat for alpha values, it is fairly trivial to calculate:

Alpha based on luminosity         = (R + G + B) / 3;

Alpha based on channel presidence = Max(R,G,B);

Blended transparency with an alpha threshold of 127 would mean that every pixel that passed the alpha test with a value of 127 or lower would be blended and those above 127 would be hard masked.

I hope that helps clarify a little bit, just in case its not clear. Awesome code guys.