# GPUImageMovie Not Support Alpha Channel?

Tags: ios, video, gpuimage

I create Video Effect by GPUImage like this

```
self.overlayerView = [[GPUImageView alloc] init];
self.overlayerView.frame = self.view.frame;

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    
    NSURL *sourceURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"212121" withExtension:@"mp4"];
    GPUImageMovie *sourceMovie = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:sourceURL];
    sourceMovie.playAtActualSpeed = YES;
    sourceMovie.shouldRepeat = YES;
    
    sourceMovie.shouldIgnoreUpdatesToThisTarget = YES;
    
    NSURL *maskURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"rose" withExtension:@"mp4"];
    GPUImageMovie *maskMovie = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:maskURL];
    maskMovie.playAtActualSpeed = YES;
    maskMovie.shouldRepeat = YES;
    
    
    NSURL *alphaURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"rose_alpha" withExtension:@"mp4"];
    GPUImageMovie *alphaMovie = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:alphaURL];
    alphaMovie.playAtActualSpeed = YES;
    alphaMovie.shouldRepeat = YES;
    
    
    NSURL *topURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"screen" withExtension:@"mp4"];
    GPUImageMovie *topMovie = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:topURL];
    topMovie.playAtActualSpeed = YES;
    topMovie.shouldRepeat = YES;
    
    filter0 = [[GPUImageThreeInputFilter alloc] initWithFragmentShaderFromString:@"precision highp float;uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2;uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture3;varying vec2 textureCoordinate;void main(){vec4 video=texture2D(inputImageTexture,textureCoordinate);vec4 mv=texture2D(inputImageTexture2, textureCoordinate);vec4 alpha = texture2D(inputImageTexture3, textureCoordinate);gl_FragColor = video * (1.0 - alpha.r) + mv;}"];
    

    filter1 = [[GPUImageTwoInputFilter  alloc] initWithFragmentShaderFromString:@"\nprecision highp float;\nuniform sampler2D inputImageTexture; //video\nuniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2; //screen\nvarying vec2 textureCoordinate;\nvoid main()\n{\nvec4 video = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);\nvec4 screen = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, textureCoordinate);\nmediump vec4 whiteColor = vec4(1.0);\ngl_FragColor = whiteColor - ((whiteColor - screen) * (whiteColor - video));\n}"];


    [sourceMovie addTarget:filter0];
    [maskMovie addTarget:filter0];
    [alphaMovie addTarget:filter0];
    [filter0 addTarget:filter1];
    [topMovie addTarget:filter1];

    [sourceMovie startProcessing];
    [alphaMovie startProcessing];
    [maskMovie startProcessing];
    [topMovie startProcessing];

    [filter0 forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(480,480)];
    [filter1 forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(480,480)];
    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [filter1 addTarget:self.overlayerView];
    });
});
```

Code can run and i got the video effect like this
[image]

The video has a black background that is because the alphaMovie not play the same time with the maskMovie?

This is what i want to create
[image]

The effect video no black background

Question:

1: How can i remove the black background ?

2: Why i the effect video have black background ?

Comment: @Brad Larson Please Help me ..

Answer (score 2):

The GPUImage framework does not contain support for an alpha channel feature like that. There is a green screen feature, so if you pre-produce your video against a green screen then it is possible to split the video from the green screen background. But, what you describe here is an alpha channel video and a second video and that it not going to work properly because you are pulling from two different video sources at the same time and they will not stay in sync. Note that even with the green screen feature, there are issues with the exact edges, as described in [this blog post](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post18_green_screen/) (includes source code). The basic problem is that edges that are near green but not exactly green can be treated in odd ways by the filter ramp. Another approach you might want to think about is to just precompose the N frames down to 1 video before attempting to playback the video with the iOS video logic.

Comment: Thank for your respone, But I still no idea how to fix this problem. could you send more info to me . Thanks ~~~~

Comment: You are attempting something that is not supported currently, as far as I know. The specific details are covered in my blog post linked above, please have a look. The blog post describes a library that implements what I consider a better solution, but like all things it depends on what your specific needs are.

Comment: I have read your blog again and again, Finally I think would be vertex shader problem. it's right ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are really looking for, yes the problem is related to a vertex shader but it also has to do with the source of your shader data (it has to come from multiple h.264 streams in sync). This is not a trivial problem by any stretch of the imagination. You could read more about shaders here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550488/glkit-masking-or-blending-2-textures-both-from-jpegs-no-alphas or if you want to take a look at an actual working solution you could have a look at http://www.modejong.com/blog/post4_h_264_video_with_an_alpha_channel which actually works.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to make the GPUImageMovie play two video at same time.

Comment: I just added a link here that also solves this problem directly with OpenGL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12128695/763355