# Coding Using Transparent Images

Tags: image, alpha, translucency

I understand that languages often have a function for removing a single color (like a RGB(255,0,0) background) but what about for images that are semi translucent?  Ex: smoke has color but you can see behind it because of the alpha channel.  I'm just curious how this is done in code.  Also, I write in c++ and python.  Thanks ahead!

Comment: Example implementation with RGB and Alpha channel: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35004399/763355