# ARKit / SpriteKit - set pixelBufferAttributes to SKVideoNode or make transparent pixels in video (chroma-key effect) another way

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, arkit, skvideonode

My goal is to present 2D animated characters in the real environment using `ARKit`. The animated characters are part of a video at presented in the following snapshot from the video:

[image: Snapshot from the video]

Displaying the video itself was achieved with no problem at all using the code:

```
func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode? {
    guard let urlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "resourceName", ofType: "mp4") else { return nil }

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: urlString)
    let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
    let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)

    let videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player)
    videoNode.size = CGSize(width: 200.0, height: 150.0)
    videoNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)

    return videoNode
}
```

The result of this code is presented in the screen shot from the app below as expected:

[image: App screenshot #1]

But as you can see, the background of the characters isn't very nice, so I need to make it vanish, in order to create the illusion of the characters actually standing on the horizontal plane surface.
I'm trying to achieve this by making a chroma-key effect to the video.

- *For those who are not familiar with chroma-key, this is name of the "green screen effect" seen sometimes on TV to make a color transparent.*

My approach to the chroma-key effect is to create a custom filter based on `"CIColorCube" CIFilter`, and then apply the filter to the video using `AVVideoComposition`.

First, is the code for creating the filter:

```
func RGBtoHSV(r : Float, g : Float, b : Float) -> (h : Float, s : Float, v : Float) {
    var h : CGFloat = 0
    var s : CGFloat = 0
    var v : CGFloat = 0
    let col = UIColor(red: CGFloat(r), green: CGFloat(g), blue: CGFloat(b), alpha: 1.0)
    col.getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &v, alpha: nil)
    return (Float(h), Float(s), Float(v))
}

func colorCubeFilterForChromaKey(hueAngle: Float) -> CIFilter {

    let hueRange: Float = 20 // degrees size pie shape that we want to replace
    let minHueAngle: Float = (hueAngle - hueRange/2.0) / 360
    let maxHueAngle: Float = (hueAngle + hueRange/2.0) / 360

    let size = 64
    var cubeData = [Float](repeating: 0, count: size * size * size * 4)
    var rgb: [Float] = [0, 0, 0]
    var hsv: (h : Float, s : Float, v : Float)
    var offset = 0

    for z in 0 ..< size {
        rgb[2] = Float(z) / Float(size) // blue value
        for y in 0 ..< size {
            rgb[1] = Float(y) / Float(size) // green value
            for x in 0 ..< size {

                rgb[0] = Float(x) / Float(size) // red value
                hsv = RGBtoHSV(r: rgb[0], g: rgb[1], b: rgb[2])
                // TODO: Check if hsv.s > 0.5 is really nesseccary
                let alpha: Float = (hsv.h > minHueAngle && hsv.h < maxHueAngle && hsv.s > 0.5) ? 0 : 1.0

                cubeData[offset] = rgb[0] * alpha
                cubeData[offset + 1] = rgb[1] * alpha
                cubeData[offset + 2] = rgb[2] * alpha
                cubeData[offset + 3] = alpha
                offset += 4
            }
        }
    }
    let b = cubeData.withUnsafeBufferPointer { Data(buffer: $0) }
    let data = b as NSData

    let colorCube = CIFilter(name: "CIColorCube", withInputParameters: [
        "inputCubeDimension": size,
        "inputCubeData": data
        ])
    return colorCube!
}
```

And then the code for applying the filter to the video by modifying the function `func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode?` that I wrote earlier:

```
func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode? {
    guard let urlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "resourceName", ofType: "mp4") else { return nil }

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: urlString)
    let asset = AVAsset(url: url)

    let filter = colorCubeFilterForChromaKey(hueAngle: 38)
    let composition = AVVideoComposition(asset: asset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { request in
        let source = request.sourceImage
        filter.setValue(source, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        let output = filter.outputImage

        request.finish(with: output!, context: nil)
    })

    let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    item.videoComposition = composition
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)

    let videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player)
    videoNode.size = CGSize(width: 200.0, height: 150.0)
    videoNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)

    return videoNode
}
```

The code is supposed to replace all pixels of each frame of the video to `alpha = 0.0` if the pixel color match the hue range of the background.
But instead of getting transparent pixels I'm getting those pixels black as can be seen in the image below:

[image: App screenshot #2]

Now, even though this is not the wanted effect, it does not surprise me, as I knew that this is the way iOS displays videos with alpha channel.
But here is the real problem - When displaying a normal video in an `AVPlayer`, there is an option to add an `AVPlayerLayer` to the view, and to set `pixelBufferAttributes` to it, to let the player layer know we use a transparent pixel buffer, like so:

```
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.bounds = view.bounds
playerLayer.position = view.center
playerLayer.pixelBufferAttributes = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String): kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
```

This code gives us a video with transparent background (**GOOD!**) but a fixed size and position (**NOT GOOD...**), as you can see in this screenshot:

[image: App screenshot #3]

I want to achieve the same effect, but on `SKVideoNode`, and not on `AVPlayerLayer`. However, I can't find any way to set `pixelBufferAttributes` to `SKVideoNode`, and setting a player layer does not achieve the desired effect of `ARKit` as it is fixed in position.

Is there any solution to my problem, or maybe is there another technique to achieve the same desired effect?

Comment: Not sure it’ll work, but you could try doing it in 3D with SceneKit (`ARSCNView`) and using `AVPlayer` as the material contents for a plane.

Comment: Check section 1 ' Transparent Videos in SpriteKit' of this Medium post: https://medium.com/@quentinfasquel/ios-transparent-video-in-spritekit-then-scenekit-2fc66b8706a6

Comment: @KNV Quite funny, I talked with Quentin Fasquel who wrote this article on medium. He gave me a hint to use the SKEffectNode, but he is using a shader and I used a filter in my final solution.

Comment: @rickster This might work but I rather not use 3D in this specific case.

Comment: @2shy hehe nice! Maybe you can help me a little bit because I'm using your colorCubeFilterForChromaKey and RGBtoHSV code. I'm adding the effectNode as a child of SKScene since I want the video to play in a SCNPlane. But when I do this, the filtering is not working...

Comment: You guys might be interested in a green screen for iOS blog post that I wrote up, linked from the SO answer about green screen vs alpha channel question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35004399/763355

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is quite simple!
All that needs to be done is to add the video as a child of a `SKEffectNode` and apply the filter to the `SKEffectNode` instead of the video itself (the `AVVideoComposition` is not necessary).
Here is the code I used:

```
func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode? {
    // Create and configure a node for the anchor added to the view's session.
    let bialikVideoNode = videoNodeWith(resourceName: "Tsina_05", ofType: "mp4")
    bialikVideoNode.size = CGSize(width: kDizengofVideoWidth, height: kDizengofVideoHeight)
    bialikVideoNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)

    // Make the video background transparent using an SKEffectNode, since chroma-key doesn't work on video
    let effectNode = SKEffectNode()
    effectNode.addChild(bialikVideoNode)
    effectNode.filter = colorCubeFilterForChromaKey(hueAngle: 120)

    return effectNode
}
```

And here is the result as needed:
[image]

Comment: is it possible to remove only one color from the video

Comment: @Mashhadi You can reduce the value of hueRange in the colorCubeFilterForChromaKey(hueAngle:) function to remove a small range of hues  (almost a single color).

Comment: I have a video having simple black color so changed my hue to effectNode.filter = colorCubeFilterForChromaKey(hueAngle: 1) but still don't works

Comment: @Mashhadi This only works with colors other than black and white as black and white aren't considered as hues... Sorry my friend.

Comment: This is great.. how do you define a different color than that yellow, for example pure red, as the background color? As much as I try it only seems to make blacks transparent for some reason.

Comment: @JacoboKoenig The value for hueAngle determines the color of the background. In my example code the value is 120 which is green. Pure red is either 0 or 360.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you! Had the same problem + mixing [AR/Scene/Sprite]Kit. But I would recommend to use this algorithm instead. It gives a better result:

```
...
var r: [Float] = removeChromaKeyColor(r: rgb[0], g: rgb[1], b: rgb[2])
                cubeData[offset] = r[0]
                cubeData[offset + 1] = r[1]
                cubeData[offset + 2] = r[2]
                cubeData[offset + 3] = r[3]
                offset += 4
...

func removeChromaKeyColor(r: Float, g: Float, b: Float) -> [Float] {
    let threshold: Float = 0.1
    let refColor: [Float] = [0, 1.0, 0, 1.0]    // chroma key color

    //http://www.shaderslab.com/demo-40---video-in-video-with-green-chromakey.html
    let val = ceil(saturate(g - r - threshold)) * ceil(saturate(g - b - threshold))
    var result = lerp(a: [r, g, b, 0.0], b: refColor, w: val)
    result[3] = fabs(1.0 - result[3])

    return result
}

func saturate(_ x: Float) -> Float {
    return max(0, min(1, x));
}

func ceil(_ v: Float) -> Float {
    return -floor(-v);
}

func lerp(a: [Float], b: [Float], w: Float) -> [Float] {
    return [a[0]+w*(b[0]-a[0]), a[1]+w*(b[1]-a[1]), a[2]+w*(b[2]-a[2]), a[3]+w*(b[3]-a[3])];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This filters the green colors better than the accepted answer.

Comment: Hey @myz how do i change the color that is being made transparent. It seems from your code that it should be the refColor, however changing this doesnt make a difference. I would really appreciate the help :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have access to this old code anymore, but yes, refColor should be the transparent color: (red, green, blue, alpha=1.0) [0.0-1.0].

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. It doesn't seem to work though. No matter what I change the refColor to it filters out the green.